# solving dynamic system with dde23 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I looked at the scientific paper published in January this year.
I am now trying to create a code, but may I show you it and tell me whether it is correct or not.

The code is related to this system. My problem is that the code does not work unless I change the last equation which written green after % in my code.

```
function chemonotreatment
clear; clc; close all
 t0 = 0; tfinal = 40;
 alpha_1 = 1.5; alpha_2 = 10;
 K1 = 1460; K2 = 2100;
 L1 = 1750; L2 = 2300;
 q_1 = 0.0075; q_2 = 0.005;
 r_1 = 0.002; r_2 = 0.001;
 beta_1 = 2; beta_2 = 12;
 delta = 0.1; eipson = 0.0001;
 options = ddeset('RelTol', 1e-9, 'AbsTol', 1e-5, 'InitialY',[1460;0.01 ; 1750; 0]); 
 taw = 20;

sol1 = dde23(@chemonotreatment, [], [1460;0.01 ; 1750; 0],[t0, tfinal],options)
 T =  [0:1:40]
 Y = deval(sol1,T)
 
 sol2 = dde23(@chemonotreatment, taw,Y(:,2),[0, tfinal],options)
 figure (1), plot (sol2.x, sol2.y(1,:)), grid on, hold on
  figure (2), plot (sol2.x, sol2.y(2,:)), grid on, hold on
  figure (3), plot (sol2.x, sol2.y(3,:)), grid on, hold on
  figure (4), plot (sol2.x, sol2.y(4,:)), grid on, hold on
  
figure(5), plot (T,Y)
  function dw = chemonotreatment (t,w,Z) 
      dw = zeros (4,1);
     
        
        x1 = w(1);
        x2 = w(2);
        u1 = w(3);
        u2 = w(4);
        
        if isempty(Z) 
              dw(1) = alpha_1*x1*(1-(x1/K1)) - q_1*x1*x2;
         dw(2) = alpha_2*x2*(1-(x2/K2)) - q_2*x1*x2 - delta*x2;
         dw(3) = beta_1*u1*(1-(u1/L1)) - r_1*u1*u2;
         dw(4) = beta_2*u2*(1-(u2/L2)) - r_2*u1*u2 + (eipson*delta*x2);
        else
            ylag = Z(2);
         dw(1) = alpha_1*x1*(1-(x1/K1)) - q_1*x1*x2;
         dw(2) = alpha_2*x2*(1-(x2/K2)) - q_2*x1*x2 - delta*x2;
         dw(3) = beta_1*u1*(1-(u1/L1)) - r_1*u1*u2;
         dw(4) = beta_2*u2*(1-(u2/L2)) - r_2*u1*u2 + (eipson*delta*ylag);
        % dw(4) = beta_2*ylag*(1-(u2/L2)) - r_2*u1*u2 + (eipson*delta*u2);
        end
  end

end
```

Comment: Your snippet wraps the entire code  in an extra, incomplete `function chemonotreatment` and `end`, which isn't valid syntax at all. Also "in green"? There is no green. I am afraid that it is very difficult to understand what you are asking; please consider a translation service.

Comment: If we delete line 44 and replace it with line 45 after deleting the mark, it works even though the system does not have line 45.